# Large subsets of the Hamming cube with small intersections with all spheres of given radius

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

What is the maximal cardinality of a subset $A$ of $\{-1,1\}^n$ such that any Hamming sphere with radius $r$ contains at most $k$ elements of $A$?

Are explicit constructions with large cardinality known?
Any relevant comment or reference appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two words: list decoding

Apparently the previous answer is too short to be an answer, so I am writing this sentence.

Comment: ah, seems to be exactly that. Well, the question was for spheres rather than Hamming balls, but the case of balls might probably be enough.